# Time difference between Time Period and Instant 1

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have some time instants (A, B) and some time periods (C-D). I would like to find the time difference between each time period and the time instant matched to it. I mean that:

if the time (A or B) is between C and D

then dT = 0

I've tried doing it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [dt.datetime(2017,1,6),      dt.datetime(2017,1,4)],
                   'B': [dt.datetime(2017,1,7),      dt.datetime(2017,1,5)],
                   'C': [dt.datetime(2017,1,6,12,3), dt.datetime(2017,1,6,13,3)],
                   'D': [dt.datetime(2017,1,8,12,3), dt.datetime(2017,1,8,14,3)]})

# Calculate the time difference
def dT(Time, on, off):
    if Time < on:
        return on - Time
    elif Time > off:
        return Time - off
    else:
        return 0
dT = np.vectorize(dT)

df['dT_A'] = dT(df['A'], df['C'], df['D'])
df['dT_B'] = dT(df['B'], df['C'], df['D'])

# Change the time difference to a float
def floa(dT):
    if dT == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return dT / timedelta (days=1)
floa = np.vectorize(floa)

df['dT_A'] = floa(df['dT_A'])
df['dT_B'] = floa(df['dT_B'])
```

It calculated `dt_A` but then it gave me this error:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite  its name, `np.vectorize` is not vectorized - it works in loops. So better to work on vectors if you can, and luckily what you want is pretty easy to do in 'vanilla' Pandas:

```
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [dt.datetime(2017,1,6),      dt.datetime(2017,1,4)],
                   'B': [dt.datetime(2017,1,7),      dt.datetime(2017,1,5)],
                   'C': [dt.datetime(2017,1,6,12,3), dt.datetime(2017,1,6,13,3)],
                   'D': [dt.datetime(2017,1,8,12,3), dt.datetime(2017,1,8,14,3)]})
# default is 0
df['dT_A'] = 0
df['dT_B'] = 0

df.loc[df.A < df.C, 'dT_A'] = (df.C - df.A) .loc[df.A < df.C]
df.loc[df.A > df.D, 'dT_A'] = (df.A - df.D) .loc[df.A > df.D]

df.loc[df.B < df.C, 'dT_B'] = (df.C - df.B) .loc[df.B < df.C]
df.loc[df.B > df.D, 'dT_B'] = (df.B - df.D) .loc[df.B > df.D]

# convert timedelta to number of days, to float
df['dT_A'] = df.dT_A / dt.timedelta(days=1)
df['dT_B'] = df.dT_B / dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Josh's answer (Method A) works on my computer, however it doesn't work on my colleague's computer. On my colleague's computer, we needed to use another loc (Method B). My colleague claimed that method A was trying to put the whole column on each row. Method B works for me and for my colleague so I will edit Josh's answer to that.

**Method A**

```
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [dt.datetime(2017,1,6),      dt.datetime(2017,1,4)],
                   'B': [dt.datetime(2017,1,7),      dt.datetime(2017,1,5)],
                   'C': [dt.datetime(2017,1,6,12,3), dt.datetime(2017,1,6,13,3)],
                   'D': [dt.datetime(2017,1,8,12,3), dt.datetime(2017,1,8,14,3)]})
# default is 0
df['dT_A'] = 0
df['dT_B'] = 0

df.loc[df.A < df.C, 'dT_A'] = df.C - df.A
df.loc[df.A > df.D, 'dT_A'] = df.A - df.D

df.loc[df.B < df.C, 'dT_B'] = df.C - df.B
df.loc[df.B > df.D, 'dT_B'] = df.B - df.D

# convert timedelta to number of days, to float
df['dT_A'] = df.dT_A / dt.timedelta(days=1)
df['dT_B'] = df.dT_B / dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

**Method B**

```
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [dt.datetime(2017,1,6),      dt.datetime(2017,1,4)],
                   'B': [dt.datetime(2017,1,7),      dt.datetime(2017,1,5)],
                   'C': [dt.datetime(2017,1,6,12,3), dt.datetime(2017,1,6,13,3)],
                   'D': [dt.datetime(2017,1,8,12,3), dt.datetime(2017,1,8,14,3)]})

# default is 0
df['dT_A'] = 0
df['dT_B'] = 0

df.loc[df.A < df.C, 'dT_A'] = (df.C - df.A) .loc[df.A < df.C]
df.loc[df.A > df.D, 'dT_A'] = (df.A - df.D) .loc[df.A > df.D]

df.loc[df.B < df.C, 'dT_B'] = (df.C - df.B) .loc[df.B < df.C]
df.loc[df.B > df.D, 'dT_B'] = (df.B - df.D) .loc[df.B > df.D]

# Convert timedelta to float, number of days
df['dT_A'] = df.dT_A / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['dT_B'] = df.dT_B / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```